# Mongodb Exception String index out of range: -1

Tags: java, mongodb, mongohq

Hi i tried a program on mongodb which connect to mongohq but i am getting following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1958)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientURI.<init>(MongoClientURI.java:186)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientURI.<init>(MongoClientURI.java:138)
    at org.Mongoadded.main(Mongoadded.java:15)
```

and the code i return is :

```
package org;

import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Set;

import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;

public class Mongoadded {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException{

        String texturi="mongodb://mymail@gmail.com:password@emma.mongohq.com:10045/mongo";
        MongoClientURI mongoURI=new MongoClientURI(texturi);
        MongoClient mongoclient=new MongoClient(mongoURI);

        DB db=mongoclient.getDB("bhv");
        db.authenticate(mongoURI.getUsername(), mongoURI.getPassword());

        Set<String> colls=db.getCollectionNames();
        for(String c:colls){
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
```

and mongo-java-driver i'm using is 2.10.1 .
thankyou in advance

Comment: Is your authentication correct?? Are you getting `true` for  `db.authenticate(mongoURI.getUsername(), mongoURI.getPassword());` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually we have to create a new user for database .. and submit that values ,
its not account username,password . Its **dbusername** ,**dbpassword** .

i tried but it not working in mongohq..

and in the same way i tried in [mongolab](https://mongolab.com/) its worked fine.

and if anyone know to how to do in mongohq please let me know Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I meet the same problem now. Can you explain more specifically? What is **dbusername** and **dbpassword**? I mean, I can create a new user in *mLab Mongodb*, but how to use it in the code, like `getUsername()` and `getPassword()`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is in the username: mymail@gmail.com

The mongo client driver is actually relying on the index of `@` to separate the authentication information from host name. Your code is not even reaching the `db.authenticate` part. It is failing at the constructor `MongoClientURI(texturi)`

Comment: This is definitely a very bad answer.